# Continuous factors for invertible simple tensors

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras

Our  following question is motivated  by [this very  interesting answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258293/is-a-pointwise-simple-tensor-valued-continuous-map-a-tensor-product-of-two-co/258297#258297)

Assume that $A$  is  a  $C^{*}$ algebra. Put  $X=\{a\otimes b \mid a,b \in G(A)\}$  where  $G(A)$ is the  space of  all invertible  elements  of  $A$.

Assume  that  there  are two  continuous  maps  $f,g: X \to A$  such that $ x=f(x)\otimes g(x),\;\;\;\forall x \in X$.

> Does this  imply that $A$ is  a finite  dimensional  commmutative  algebra?

Note:  After  a few  modification the  above   question can be  generalized to the category of  Banach spaces or other similar  categories.

For  example on can consider the  following:

> "Classification of  all  Banach space $V$ such that  for  every tensor product norm with $\parallel x\otimes y \parallel= \parallel x \parallel. \parallel y \parallel$ we  have  two  continuous  maps $f,g$ from the  space  of  simple  tensors  to $V$ (or  from $V \bar{\otimes} V$  to  $V$) with $x=f(x) \otimes g(x)$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't get "finite dimensional", since this is true for all infinite-dimensional commutative $C^*$-algebras too.

We can suppose $A = C_0(\Omega)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff $\Omega$.  Then $X$ is identified with an appropriate subset of $C_0(\Omega^2)$: those $x : \Omega^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ which can be written $x(\omega_1, \omega_2) = a(\omega_1) b(\omega_2)$ where $a,b \in C_0(\Omega)$ are invertible, i.e.  nowhere vanishing.

Fix some $\omega_0 \in \Omega$ and put
$$f(x)(\omega) = \frac{x(\omega, \omega_0)}{\sqrt{x(\omega_0, \omega_0)}}, \qquad g(x)(\omega) = \frac{x(\omega_0, \omega)}{\sqrt{x(\omega_0, \omega_0)}}.$$
Then $f,g : X \to A$ are continuous, and for any $x \in X$, by writing $x = a \otimes b$, it's easy to check that you have $f(x) \otimes g(x) = x$.

Comment: Very elegant answer. Thank you  very  much. Do you think that for  $A=B(H)$, such maps f,g do not exist?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I have not thought about it and may not have a chance to do so.